# Can't resize Dash Icons in Settings (No option)

Tags: icons, resize

I booted my computer today and noticed that the icons on my Ubuntu Default Dash were too big, when I went under Appearances in Settings, there wasn't an option for decreasing the size of the Dash, in fact, no option to resize or configure the Dash at all, only giving me the option to pick a Background Image, under the appearances tab at the top, it only gives me the option to choose light theme or dark theme:

[image]

[image]

Addtional Info:

**My Operating system is Ubuntu**

The output of `lsb_release -a` command is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I did not install Dash to Dock
I tried turning off Ubuntu Dock in GNOME Tweaks, didn't help.

My objective is to resize the dash icon size, anything helps!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't support Pop!_OS here. Only standard Ubuntu. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or find the Pop!_OS support forum.

Answer (score 0):

You did change something in your gnome/ubuntu.

This is how this menu looks on my ubuntu

[Settings - Appearance (I have too little reputation points to make the image visible here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLW9Y.png)

Comment: Problem is that my operating system is Ubuntu, I donno why it just like switched to Pop

Comment: Ubuntu Dock is a thinned Dash to dock/Dash to panel integrated into the system. Bottom line, if you install dash to dock or Dash to panel, the configuration changes done to dash to dock likely will be also applied to ubuntu dock. Once you are done with your settings then remove Dash to Dock/Dash to panle, as 2 docks will not look good.

I did use one of those extensions to edit some config of the Ubuntu Dock which ubuntu doesn't expose, just don't remember which one.

On your ubuntu, you did install something to change its look into Pop!_OS